# Can contour integration be used to integrate $~u^u(1-u)^{1-u}~$?

Tags: contour-integration

I am told contour integration can be used to show

$$\int_0^1 e^{i \pi z} z^z(1-z)^{1-z}=\frac{i\pi e}{24}$$

but am skeptical as the integrand contains log functions which do not admit simple closed contours for example to use the Residue Theorem.  However I suspect perhaps a pochhammer contour might work, i.e, a (closed) analytically-continuous figure-8 contour going around $~0~$ and $~1~$ similar to the integral representation of the beta function.  Might someone be familiar with this integral and the method used to integrate it and give me some ideas?

Thanks,
Dominic

Comment: It looks like Beta Function...

Comment: Yes however in the beta function the exponents are held constant.

Comment: The addendum in [this old answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2113495/44121) appears to be related.

Comment: @metamorphy:  Thanks.  I'll work through it.